# Compare values independently in C#

Tags: c#

Let's say I have three integers

```
int A = 43;
int B = 33;
int C = 23;
```

I'd like my code for each iteration:

1. Take the *two highest* integers and subtract `1` from them
2. Take the rest (*lowest*) one and add `1` to it.
3. Tie (if we have several lowest items) should be resolved *at random*.
4. The iterations should *end* when at least `2` integers are equal to `0`.

E.g. for `A = 43; B = 33; C = 23` the sequence should be

```
A       B       C

43      33      23
42      32      24
41      31      25
40      30      26
39      29      27
38      28      28 
37      27      29 <- may vary since we resolve tie at random: {37, 29, 27} is valid
36      28      28
...
```

My **current attempt** is:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    int A = 43;
    int B = 33;
    int C = 23;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(A + "\t" + B + "\t" + C);

        do
        {
            Iteration(A, B, C);
            Console.WriteLine(A + "\t" + B + "\t" + C);
        }
        while (...); //At least two variables are bigger than 0
    }

    private void Iteration(ref int A, ref int B, ref int C)
    {
        /*
        Increase the smallest variable by 1.
        Decrease the two bigger variables by 1.

        When the two smallest variables are the same, 
        choose one at random and increase it by 1.
        Add 1 to the other smallest variable and the bigger one.
        */
    }
}
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
A       B       C

43      33      23
42      32      24
41      31      25
40      30      26
39      29      27
38      28      28
37      27      29
36      28      28
35      29      27
34      28      28
33      27      29
32      28      28
31      27      29
...     ...     ...
```

I've already tried to do it with many comparisons but I want the code to be cleaner. I've thought about using the `ref` keyword for example but I didn't find a way how to do it?

Has someone got an idea?

Comment: "I've already tried" > Show us and we might be able to help you. (Code reviews usually don't do well here, but let us judge that when there is actually something to answer)

Comment: I did things like `if(A > B && A > C)` and so on many and many times until I covered every possible case. But I want the code to be clearer and don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: Not sure if this would help in your case as you haven't posted much code but maybe look at a `Collection` or `Array` to add the values to and use methods on this collection to get the lowest.

Comment: "End when two integers are equal to 0", if they all start as positive values, your logic ensures they will never reach zero. I think you need to focus on one thing at a time, and post some code and the problems you have with it. However, as have already been pointed out, if the code works, you just want to improve it, the question will be better suited on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: So I edited my question now, maybe it is clearer now

Comment: Never mind my comment, I misunderstood what you meant about ties.

Answer (score 0):

Let's *generalize* the problem: it's easier to solve (*collection* manipulation is easier than with `3` items). So far, so good on each iteration

1. Add `1` to *min* item; if there're *several* min item, take arbitrary one
2. Subract `1` from all the *rest* items

We can easily implement these rules with a help of *Linq*:

**Code:**

```
// Simplest, not thread-safe
private static Random s_Random = new Random(); 

private static int[] NextIteration(int[] value) {
  int minValue = value.Min();

  int[] minIndexes = value
    .Select((item, index) => item == minValue 
       ? index 
       : -1)
    .Where(index => index >= 0)
    .ToArray();

  int minIndex = minIndexes.Length == 1
    ? minIndexes[0]
    : minIndexes[s_Random.Next(minIndexes.Length)]; // 

  return value
    .Select((item, index) => index == minIndex 
       ? item + 1  // increment an item at chosen minIndex
       : item - 1) // decrement all the other items
    .ToArray();
}
```

Finally, we implement a sequence *generator* (in which we add the final requirement - "iterations should end when at least two integers are equal to 0"):

```
  private static IEnumerable<int[]> AllIterations(int[] value) {
    for (int[] data = value; 
               data.Count(item => item == 0) < value.Length - 1; 
               data = NextIteration(data))
      yield return data;
  }
```

**Demo:**

```
var result = AllIterations(new[] {43, 33, 23})
  .Take(20)                                  // Let's have a look at top 20 items
  .Select(line => string.Join("\t", line));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));

// How many iterations does it take to come to the end?
Console.WriteLine(""); 
Console.WriteLine($"{AllIterations(new[] {43, 33, 23}).Count()} iterations required.");
```

**Outcome:** (may *vary* since we take *arbitrary* item on tie)

```
43  33  23
42  32  24
41  31  25
40  30  26
39  29  27
38  28  28
37  27  29
36  28  28
35  29  27
34  28  28
33  27  29
32  28  28
31  27  29
30  28  28
29  27  29
28  28  28
29  27  27
28  26  28
27  27  27
28  26  26  

97 iterations required.
```